# jquery.on() does not work

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, handlebars.js

I have the following HTML structure,which is a [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template.:

```
<div class="row" id="{{serviceId}}">
            <div class="favorites" isfavorite="{{isFavorite}}">
                <img src="{{favImg}}" style="width:25px;">
            </div>
            <!-- end .favorites -->
            <div class="service">
                <p class="title">{{serviceName}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small serviceStat">

            </div>
            <div class="small metric">

            </div>
            <div class="performance"></div>
            <div class="icon email">
                <img src="../images/email.png" style="width:27px">
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i try to bind an event to the email class using the `.on()` method it does not work:

```
$('.row').on('click','.email',function(){alert('clicked')});

 //or like this:
$('.email').on('click',function(){alert('clicked')});
```

But if i bind it with live it works:

```
$('.email').live('click',function(){alert('clicked')});
```

any idea what might cause it?

Comment: I've taken your code as is **WITHOUT ANY MODIFICATIONS** and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/y4Khy/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  If you are using jQuery 1.6 and below then that's probably why

Comment: You are using the wrong .on syntax. This question has been asked hundreds of times, if not thousands.

Comment: @Kevin B: why's that? The syntax **is correct**

Comment: The syntax is correct, however it is the wrong version of the syntax. The syntax currently being used is for binding to an existing .email element. In this case, .email doesn't exist yet (neither does .row). (proven by the fact that it works with `.live`)

Comment: @Kevin B: `$('.row').on('click','.email',function(){alert('clicked')});` - this doesn't mean "being used is for binding to an existing .email element". This does mean binding to an existing `.row` element.

Comment: @zerkms `.row` is part of the template too. If `.email` doesn't exist, `.row` probably doesn't either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you need to bind your delegate handler ABOVE [the location where your `.row` elements are going to exist] in the DOM...

If you have:

```
<div id="item-container">
    <!--divs with class row go in here -->
</div>
```

you need to do this:

```
$('#item-container').on('click', '.email', function() {alert('clicked'); });
```

The reason for this is *instances* of your template do not exist in the DOM at document ready...so you need to bind the event to an element that *does* exist...aka, the `item-container`

Comment: Thanks, I know that in the new jquery versions, live event is translated into `.on` eventually so I thought it works the same and will bind itself automatically once the element is created, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
$('.row').on('click','.email',function(){alert('clicked')});

 //or like this:
$('.email').on('click',function(){alert('clicked')})
```

Needs to be within this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* Code goes here */
});
```

I am guessing it isn't. (This is to ensure that events are bound after the DOM is ready).

Either that, or you are using an old version of jQuery. `.on` was added in one of the more recent versions.